# Write attribute column names (fields) in a PyQGIS list based on their attribute value

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a tricky question: for a QGIS script, I need to filter a list of attribute column names (fields) of a vector based on the attribute value of each column.

My Vector is structured like this:

[image: Attributtable]

I create the list of field names with:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(Input_Layer, "ogr")
fields = layer.pendingFields()
field_names = [field.name() for field in fields]
```

So `field_names` gives me a list of all the attribute field names:

```
[u'NAME_A', u'NAME_B', u'NAME_C']
```

I now need to filer the list, so attribute fields are only listed in `field_names` if the attribute value (there is only one attribute) is not `NULL`. So the result should only list:

```
[u'NAME_A', u'NAME_C']
```

I can't figure it out. Running QGIS 2.18.18 on Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
fields = layer.pendingFields()
field_names = [field.name() for field in fields]

temp = list(field_names)
for field in temp:
    index  = layer.fieldNameIndex(field)
    values = layer.uniqueValues(index)

    # if "any" record has null field value, remove that field
    if None in values:
        field_names.remove(field)

    # If "all" records have null value, then remove that field
    # if None in values and len(values)==1:
        # field_names.remove(field)
```

Sample table: (Empty cells have null value)

[image]

```
print(field_names)
# OUT: [u'c']
```

But note that: If type of any field is string and you delete field value (you get empty field), It won't be `null`, just empty string.

Comment: Great, I tryed the code and it worked so far as expected! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hm, there must be a slide mistake in the code. The result is right, all the fields that are != NULL remain in the list, but there are always also  fields in the list that have NULL field values. It must have something todo with the index that changes after removing the filed in the for loop…

Comment: You're 'right. I editted the answer.